DLIB with CUDA and CUDNN: import dlib error
I followed this instruction online (https://gist.github.com/gipinze/52531983fb47621d51c8d33dacefca49) to create a Python venv with cuda support for dlib.
I'm using: VS 17 2022, cuda 12.5, cudnn 8.9.5
I did:
conda create -n dlib-gpu python=3.8 cmake ipython
conda activate dlib-gpu
git clone https://github.com/davisking/dlib.git
cd dlib
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -T host=x64 -DDLIB_USE_CUDA=1 -DUSE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1 ..
cmake --build . --config Release
cd ..
python setup.py install -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" --set USE_AVX_INSTRUCTIONS=1 --set DLIB_USE_CUDA=1 --no DLIB_GIF_SUPPORT

After running all those commands, I tried importing dlib in ipython and got this error:
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import dlib

File D:\anaconda3\envs\dlib-gpu\lib\site-packages\dlib-19.24.99-py3.8-win-amd64.egg\dlib\__init__.py:19
     16     add_lib_to_dll_path('D:/cudnn-windows-x86_64-8.9.5.29_cuda12-archive/lib/x64/cudnn.lib')
     17     add_lib_to_dll_path('C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v12.5/lib/x64/cudart.lib')
---> 19 from _dlib_pybind11 import *
     20 from _dlib_pybind11 import __version__, __time_compiled__

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _dlib_pybind11: The specified module could not be found.

I tried:
pip freeze | grep dlib
dlib==19.24.99

Can you help me so I can use dlib with cuda enabled? I expect the instruction from the link above to return True for dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA. Thank you so much.

I don't know how but in init.py at "path\to\anaconda3\envs\dlib-gpu\Lib\site-packages\dlib-19.24.99-py3.11-win-amd64.egg\dlib", I changed if '1' == 'ON' to if 'ON' == 'ON' and it works. I'm able to run dlib on my GPU now.
enter image description here
